# sessionfactory is null in Spring MVC+hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have configured the sessionfactory in my servlet xml and injected the same into a bean by SETTER injection.  I have put a log in the setter method of bean. Upon server start am getting the log.  It seems like it is injecting the property into my bean.  but when i call the method, it is coming as null.  Attached my code..

```
<** Bean configuration Starts **>
<bean id="userServiceImpl" class="com.springapp.oranju.Service.UserServiceImpl">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>  
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="configLocation">
<value>/WEB-INF/config/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>            
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dialect}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<** Bean configuration ends **>
<** Bean Class starts**>
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;   
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
try {
System.out.println(" **********************************************************************************"+this.sessionFactory.getReference());
} catch (NamingException e) {   
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void validateLogin(UserVO userVO) {      
System.out.println(sessionFactory);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(new User(new UserVO()));
}
}
<** Bean Class ends**>
<** call from controller starts **>
UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl();
userService.validateLogin(new UserVO());
<** call from controller ends **>
I have tried using the @ Autowired.. but it was helpless.
Awaiting for a answer !.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to autowire UserServiceImpl in controller. If you instantiate it manually by **new UserServiceImpl()**, spring IoC container has no idea that UserServiceImpl depends on sessionFactory.

include the following element in you application context xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

where the base-package element is a common parent package for the service classes, and if you are using spring mvc, autowird service in your controller by:

```
@Controller public class ExampleController {

    @Autowired private UserServiceImpl userService;

}
```